# How to correctly return the result from Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement verification using Cloud Function and Twilio. Twilio works correctly and SMS with the code is sent, but in the Flutter application I get the error **[firebase_functions / deadline-exceeded] DEADLINE_EXCEEDE**. What am I doing wrong?

Cloud Function:

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

exports.sendSms = (req, res) => {
  console.log('start sendSms');
  var func = client.verify.services('xxxxx')
    .verifications
    .create({to: req.body.data.phone, channel: 'sms'})
    .then(verification => {return verification})
    .then(result => {
      if (result.status === 'pending')
        return {status: 'success', result: "pending"};
      else
        return {status: 'error', error_code: -1, error_msg: result.status};
    })
    .catch(e => {
      return {status: 'error', error_code: e.code, error_msg: e.message};
    });

  return Promise.all([func]).then(result => {
    console.log(result); // console output [ { status: 'success', result: 'pending' } ]
    return result[0];
  });
};
```

Flutter:

```
HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west3').httpsCallable(
      'send-sms',
      options: HttpsCallableOptions(timeout: const Duration(seconds: 10))
);
dynamic results = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{'phone': phoneNumber});
```

Comment: I have seen this error with Firestore in Cloud functions but I can't see any Firestore related code here. Are you using Firestore by chance in the complete code?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Firestore is used in the application, but it is not in this scenario. The error occurs exactly at the place of calling "dynamic results = await callable.call (<String, dynamic> {'phone': phoneNumber});". And the cloud function code is complete.

Comment: Is that function complete? If not can you please share your complete code and share your firebase functions version. I'll try to replicate that issue.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thank you for your willingness to help. The function code is complete, only the service identifier is replaced by "xxxxx", unfortunately I cannot provide the original one for security reasons.

Comment: have you tired `return res.send("some data");` 
you are missing to complete response, which is not closing the req-res cycle. thus causing deadline-exceeded.
try `return res.send(result[0]);` instead of `return result[0];`

Comment: It seems you missed the `functions.https.onCall` part. Can you try adding that as in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com). Also as Doug mentioned, you are trying to use callable functions which has `data, context` as parameters so you can access the phone number from body as `data.phone`

Comment: @jatinderbhola Thanks, it really helped to get rid of the problem! In the case of a not callable function, the result must be returned exactly as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The create method returns promise too  so you must add the return keyword there as well.

Instead of:

```
var func = client.verify.services('xxxxx')
```

Try this:

```
exports.sendSms = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
                //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  console.log('start sendSms');
  return client.verify.services('xxxxx')
    .verifications
    .create({to: data.phone, channel: 'sms'})
    .then(verification => {return verification})
    .then(result => {
      if (result.status === 'pending')
        return {status: 'success', result: "pending"};
      else
        return {status: 'error', error_code: -1, error_msg: result.status};
    })
    .catch(e => {
      return {status: 'error', error_code: e.code, error_msg: e.message};
    });
});
```

That being said you don't need this part:

```
return Promise.all([func]).then(result => {
    console.log(result); // console output [ { status: 'success', result: 'pending' } ]
    return result[0];
  });
```

Comment: I tried initially as you advise (that is, there was no Promise in the code), but there was the same error, so I tried adding a Promise, but the error remained.

Comment: @ecywyv I don't understand why you have that additional .then which returns verification.

Comment: This is accidentally left, you are right, this then is superfluous, removed it, but it does not affect the result

Comment: @ecywyv is doesn't seem to be a cloud function at first place

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, everything worked out! For not callable functions, the result should be returned as @jatinderbhola said, but in my case the problem was exactly what you and Doug pointed out

Comment: @ecywyv glad it was resolved. You can refer to [call functions from your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) section in the documentation for detailed information on the difference in onCall and onRequest.